# input 1 2 5 8 7 3 10 6 4 9, output 1 2 3 5 7 8 10 6 4 9

Tags: c#, sorting, numbers

i am trying to Sort the input to output I have a command "Sort from 2 to count 4" to get the final result from numbers,if mine someone to help thank you.

```
List<int> nums = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToList();
string input = Console.ReadLine();

while (true)
{
    string[] line = input.Split(" ");
    if (line[0] == "end")
    {
        break;
    }

    if (line[0] == "reverse")
    {
        int reverseFrom = int.Parse(line[2]);
        int reverseCount = int.Parse(line[4]);
        nums.Reverse(reverseFrom, reverseCount);
    }

    if (line[0] == "sort")
    {
        int sortFrom = int.Parse(line[2]);
        int sortCount = int.Parse(line[4]);
        nums.Sort(sortFrom, sortCount);
    }

    input = Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", nums));
```

Comment: Show us the code please !

Comment: int[] output = input.Take(2).Concat(input.Skip(2).Take(4).OrderBy(x => x)).Concat(input.Skip(6)).ToArray();

Comment: input 1 2 5 8 7 3 10 6 4 9, output 1 2 3 5 7 8 10 6 4 9

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try implement it as follow:

1. Enumerate all items from `0` up to `from`
2. Cache items in between `from .. from + count - 1` range, sort them an enumerate
3. Enumerate all items starting from `from + count`

Something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SortFromTo<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int from, int count, 
                                           IComparer<T> comparer) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

  if (count < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));

  comparer = null == comparer ? Comparer<T>.Default : comparer;

  if (null == comparer) 
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer), 
      $"Type {typeof(T).Name} doesn't have default comparer");     
   
  int index = -1;

  List<T> cached = new List<T>();

  foreach (T item in source) {
    index += 1;

    if (index < from || index > from + count)
      yield return item;  
    else {
      cached.Add(item);

      if (index == from + count - 1) {
        cached.Sort(comparer);

        foreach (T rec in cached)
          yield return rec;

        cached.Clear(); 
      } 
    }
  }  
}
```

Let us be nice and provide a version for comparable types:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SortFromTo<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int from, int count)
  where T : IComparable<T> => SortFromTo(source, from, count, null);
```

then you can put

```
int[] data = new int[] {1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 3, 10, 6, 4, 9};

int[] result = SortFromTo(data, 2, 4).ToArray();
```